# Removing blank entries from a Jasper report

Tags: jasper-reports

I have created a report within the jrxml. I have specified to only print the details of each value if one of my fields is populated using the tag `<printWhenExpression>` with a value like so:

```
<textField>
            <reportElement x="670" y="4" width="105" height="20" isRemoveLineWhenBlank="true">
                <printWhenExpression><![CDATA[$F{name}!= null]]></printWhenExpression>
            </reportElement>
            <textElement>
                <font fontName="Arial" size="10"/>
            </textElement>
            <textFieldExpression><![CDATA[$F{value2}]]></textFieldExpression>
```

This works in filtering only relevant data, however it leaves me with a lot of blank rows within the report. I have enabled the condition `isRemoveLineWhenBlank="true"` to remove these blank rows from being displayed on my report. This has taken my report from 12 pages to 5, however, I still observe a large number of empty rows within the report.

Here is a ScreenShot of my reports design in ireport.

[image]

And here is a ScreenShot of the report run (I've blanked out my company's name from the classes)

[image]

The full report JRXML:

```
    <?xml version="1.0" encoding="UTF-8"?>
<jasperReport xmlns="http://jasperreports.sourceforge.net/jasperreports" xmlns:xsi="http://www.w3.org/2001/XMLSchema-instance" xsi:schemaLocation="http://jasperreports.sourceforge.net/jasperreports http://jasperreports.sourceforge.net/xsd/jasperreport.xsd" name="RIOBridgeReport" pageWidth="1530" pageHeight="842" orientation="Landscape" whenNoDataType="AllSectionsNoDetail" columnWidth="555" leftMargin="10" rightMargin="5" topMargin="10" bottomMargin="10">
    <property name="ireport.zoom" value="2.0"/>
    <property name="ireport.x" value="0"/>
    <property name="ireport.y" value="0"/>
    <property name="net.sf.jasperreports.export.xls.exclude.origin.keep.first.band.1" value="columnHeader"/>
    <parameter name="title" class="java.lang.String"/>
    <parameter name="oneliner" class="java.lang.String"/>
    <field name="name" class="java.lang.String">
        <fieldDescription><![CDATA[id[starts-with(.,'USCS')]]]></fieldDescription>
    </field>
    <field name="class" class="java.lang.String">
        <fieldDescription><![CDATA[class]]></fieldDescription>
    </field>
    <field name="value" class="java.lang.String">
        <fieldDescription><![CDATA[constructor-arg/value]]></fieldDescription>
    </field>
    <field name="value1" class="java.lang.String">
        <fieldDescription><![CDATA[constructor-arg[1]/value]]></fieldDescription>
    </field>
    <field name="value2" class="java.lang.String">
        <fieldDescription><![CDATA[constructor-arg[2]/value]]></fieldDescription>
    </field>
    <variable name="runDate" class="java.lang.String">
        <initialValueExpression><![CDATA[new java.text.SimpleDateFormat("dd-MMM-yyyy HH:mm:ss Z").format(new java.util.Date())]]></initialValueExpression>
    </variable>
    <background>
        <band splitType="Stretch"/>
    </background>
    <title>
        <band height="53" splitType="Stretch">
            <textField isBlankWhenNull="true">
                <reportElement x="12" y="12" width="496" height="20"/>
                <textElement textAlignment="Center">
                    <font fontName="Arial" size="14" isBold="true"/>
                </textElement>
                <textFieldExpression><![CDATA[$P{title} + " - " + $V{runDate}]]></textFieldExpression>
            </textField>
            <image>
                <reportElement x="616" y="0" width="84" height="53"/>
                <imageExpression><![CDATA["citi_corp_logo.gif"]]></imageExpression>
            </image>
            <textField isBlankWhenNull="true">
                <reportElement x="12" y="32" width="496" height="20"/>
                <textElement textAlignment="Center">
                    <font fontName="Arial" size="10" isBold="true"/>
                </textElement>
                <textFieldExpression><![CDATA[$P{oneliner}]]></textFieldExpression>
            </textField>
        </band>
    </title>
    <columnHeader>
        <band height="23" splitType="Stretch">
            <staticText>
                <reportElement x="12" y="2" width="85" height="20"/>
                <textElement>
                    <font fontName="Arial" size="10" isBold="true" isUnderline="false"/>
                </textElement>
                <text><![CDATA[Bean Name]]></text>
            </staticText>
            <staticText>
                <reportElement x="228" y="2" width="85" height="20"/>
                <textElement>
                    <font fontName="Arial" size="10" isBold="true" isUnderline="false"/>
                </textElement>
                <text><![CDATA[Class]]></text>
            </staticText>
            <staticText>
                <reportElement x="428" y="2" width="105" height="20"/>
                <textElement>
                    <font fontName="Arial" size="10" isBold="true" isUnderline="false"/>
                </textElement>
                <text><![CDATA[Value]]></text>
            </staticText>
            <staticText>
                <reportElement x="543" y="2" width="105" height="20"/>
                <textElement>
                    <font fontName="Arial" size="10" isBold="true" isUnderline="false"/>
                </textElement>
                <text><![CDATA[Value1]]></text>
            </staticText>
            <staticText>
                <reportElement x="670" y="2" width="105" height="20"/>
                <textElement>
                    <font fontName="Arial" size="10" isBold="true" isUnderline="false"/>
                </textElement>
                <text><![CDATA[Value2]]></text>
            </staticText>
        </band>
    </columnHeader>
    <detail>
        <band height="24">
            <textField isBlankWhenNull="true">
                <reportElement x="12" y="2" width="216" height="20" isRemoveLineWhenBlank="true">
                    <printWhenExpression><![CDATA[$F{name}!= null]]></printWhenExpression>
                </reportElement>
                <textElement>
                    <font fontName="Arial" size="10"/>
                </textElement>
                <textFieldExpression><![CDATA[$F{name}]]></textFieldExpression>
            </textField>
            <textField>
                <reportElement x="228" y="2" width="185" height="20">
                    <printWhenExpression><![CDATA[$F{name}!= null]]></printWhenExpression>
                </reportElement>
                <textElement>
                    <font fontName="Arial" size="10"/>
                </textElement>
                <textFieldExpression><![CDATA[$F{class}]]></textFieldExpression>
            </textField>
            <textField>
                <reportElement x="428" y="2" width="105" height="20">
                    <printWhenExpression><![CDATA[$F{name}!= null]]></printWhenExpression>
                </reportElement>
                <textElement>
                    <font fontName="Arial" size="10"/>
                </textElement>
                <textFieldExpression><![CDATA[$F{value}]]></textFieldExpression>
            </textField>
            <textField>
                <reportElement x="543" y="4" width="105" height="20">
                    <printWhenExpression><![CDATA[$F{name}!= null]]></printWhenExpression>
                </reportElement>
                <textElement>
                    <font fontName="Arial" size="10"/>
                </textElement>
                <textFieldExpression><![CDATA[$F{value1}]]></textFieldExpression>
            </textField>
            <textField>
                <reportElement x="670" y="4" width="105" height="20">
                    <printWhenExpression><![CDATA[$F{name}!= null]]></printWhenExpression>
                </reportElement>
                <textElement>
                    <font fontName="Arial" size="10"/>
                </textElement>
                <textFieldExpression><![CDATA[$F{value2}]]></textFieldExpression>
            </textField>
        </band>
    </detail>
    <noData>
        <band height="20">
            <staticText>
                <reportElement x="146" y="0" width="200" height="20"/>
                <textElement textAlignment="Center">
                    <font fontName="Arial" size="14" isBold="true"/>
                </textElement>
                <text><![CDATA[No data found]]></text>
            </staticText>
        </band>
    </noData>
</jasperReport>
```

As you can see still a large amount of whitespace left within the report. Is there a way to completely remove them or push the blank rows to the end of the report.

Comment: Can you post the screenshot of your report's design (bands with fields) and the the screenshot of the generated report?

Answer (score 5):

Try placing everything inside a frame and add the "Remove line when blank" to the frame.

Answer (score 1):

Instead of isRemoveLineWhenBlank for a field use the band properties of detail band. Therefore this condition should be put in the detail band properties printWhenExpression. 
.